# Auto run tests after Release build

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I want to test my app only when I build it under Release configuration.
I am using Visual Studio 2013, and I haven't TFS.

I saw an option in **Test > Test Settings > Run Tests After Build**. Its working perfectly, but it works also in Debug configuration.

There is a way to run tests after build only when Release configuration is selected?